# When do I need to run "make" in my run configurations?

Tags: intellij-idea, makefile, sbt

When do I need to run "make" in my run configurations? I'm using IntelliJ 14 and each time I want to run my sbt project it seems like I need to `make`. Is this correct? Also could someone explain to me what `make` does?

Here's a screenshot of my `run` config:

[image]

Comment: "Make" is a well documented utility. You should be able to research that on your own.

Comment: "what does make do? and when should I run it?" seems like an on-topic question to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/make/info

Comment: I think the question is about the make function in IntelliJ, which is different to the make utility referenced in the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA comes with some default run configurations which depend on the type of project you set up. From your screenshot, it seems you have a Play project. When you click on `Make Project` or `Make Module`, IntelliJ builds your project according to the run configuration. In the case of a Play project, this should be equivalent to running `sbt compile` on the command line or running `compile` from the [Play console](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/PlayConsole#Compiling).

Play projects compile on the fly, and therefore, you do not need to recompile to pick up changes. You can just run the project from IntelliJ, or execute the following command from the command line `sbt run`. As long as you application is running, any changes to the code you make are automatically picked up, and your project recompiled when you reload your application in the browser.